# How to use substr at regexp of preg replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, bbcode, substr

i am making a bbcode for youtube videos.User can post a video as bbcode eg like [youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihK2pPcDSHM[/youtube]. Next, it will convert it to html code.But instead of video,i want to show also the image of the video. So i do it like this:

```
$string = preg_replace("~\[yt]http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=(.*)\[/yt]~Uis","<img src=\"http://img.youtube.com/vi/\\1/0.jpg\" />", $string);
```

It shows the image, but when somebody puts a url like:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihK2pPcDSHM&feature=channel
```

Then the image url becomes `http://img.youtube.com/vi/ihK2pPcDSHM&feature=channel1/0.jpg` which does not lead to a valid image. I am trying to change the `\\1` to `".substr('\\1', 0,11)."` but it doesnt have any result.

Any suggestion to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a different pattern like:

```
~\[yt]http://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=([a-z0-9-_]+).*?\[/yt]~is
```

Comment: thanks, but this resulted to return only one letter. so the url of the image became http://img.youtube.com/vi/l/0.jpg

Comment: @user539649: Are you sure you’re doing a case-insensitive match?

Comment: hm..what do you mean? :S i just want to show the image. have i done something wrong at the code?

Comment: @user539649: The *i* modifier in your pattern should already perform a case-insensitive match so that `[a-z]` does match both `a`–`z` and `A`–`Z`.

Comment: so now why does it returns only a letter of the video id instead of the whole video id? what should i change?

Comment: Thanks!! Finally!! I've been "fighting" with this for hours... Do you know any url so to read and learn more about the syntax of patterns? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just tell your regex to stop on the first `&` character:

```
$string = preg_replace("~\[yt]http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=([^\\&]*)\[/yt]~Uis","<img src=\"http://img.youtube.com/vi/\\1/0.jpg\" />", $string);
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it doesnt replace it. It shows the bbcode without replacing it :(

Comment: The amount of backslashes might be wrong, try getting rid of the backslashes inside `[^\\&]`.